# XCUITest - Task-kill App

Tags: ios, xcode, automated-tests, swift4, xcuitest

Trying to find a solution to automate task-kill the app for XCUITest...

```
static let springboard:XCUIApplication? = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

class func killApp(app:XCUIApplication) -> Bool
{
    app.terminate()
    if let springboard = springboard
    {
        springboard.activate()
        XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
        XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.0)
        let appTask = app.otherElements["appID"]
        if appTask.isHittable
        {
            appTask.swipeUp()
            XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            print("App task is not hittable!")
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

But it's not working. The two home button taps seem not to be recognized as a quick double-tap. Does anyone know a workable solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of depending on Springboard and double tap try this (I assume you are trying to close the app and not uninstall it)

```
closeApp(background: Bool = false) {
if (background) {
     XCUIDevice.shared().press(.home)
} else {
 application.terminate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly double-tapping home button is still not possible to achieve.